# Problem returning a value with typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, quasar-framework

I'm trying to return a value with typescript but I always end up getting the following error:

> Unsafe return of an `any` typed value.

This error is generated through a function in the @update of a select.

```
          <q-select
            outlined
            class="q-mb-lg"
            :options="rolesOptions"
            option-value="value"
            option-label="label"                
            :label="$t('Users.form.role')"
            v-model="fieldStates.role"
            @update:model-value="val => teste(val)" 
          />
```

This here would be my return, which I expect to receive the value of an option.

```
 const teste = ({value} : {value: any}) => {
   console.log('test: ', value)
   return value
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use generics to avoid the use of `any`.

```
const teste = <T>({value} : {value: T}) => {
   console.log('test: ', value)
   return value
}
```